# Get "Java Update Needed" message back

Tags: java, internet-explorer, updates

I have a user who clicked the wrong thing on this Java message:

[image: Java Update Message]

He checked the checkbox and now I don't now how to get this message back.

I tried deleting the IE and Java cache and I restored the security prompts (for Java) but the message doesn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- Reinstalling Java
- Checking the registry and appdata directories for where that information is stored
- Installing the newest Java version by hand, then you will get the message again when relevant